# Why not print more money rather than taxes?

Tags: taxes, currency

To my understanding, printing money devalues the currency because there is now more money in circulation. Now, the purpose of taxes is to absorb money back into the government directly. However, this leads to complications such that people may go through elaborate ways to avoid taxation. So, why doesn't the government just print more money for itself?